# Couldnt compile kernel with patch

Tags: kernel, compiling

I am trying to build the ubuntu 5.3.0 kernel with a custom patch. I downloaded the source and added the patch using

```
patch -p1 < patch_name.patch
```

and make a config using

```
make config
```

then I compiled it using

```
make -j6
```

This gave me the vmlinux and vmlinux.o files. I didnt know how to use them
so I tried to make the kernel into a .deb file. I used

```
make deb-pkg

fakeroot make-kpkg -j N --initrd --append-to-version=my-very-own-kernel kernel-image kernel-headers

make bindeb-pkg
```

but all of these give me the same error after compiling the whole kernel.

```
/bin/sh: 1: lz4c: not found
arch/x86/boot/compressed/Makefile:146: recipe for target 'arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux.bin.lz4' failed
make[3]: *** [arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux.bin.lz4] Error 127
make[3]: *** Deleting file 'arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux.bin.lz4'
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
arch/x86/boot/Makefile:112: recipe for target 'arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux' failed
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux] Error 2
arch/x86/Makefile:284: recipe for target 'bzImage' failed
make[1]: *** [bzImage] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/beebop/Downloads/linux-hwe-edge-5.3.0'
debian/ruleset/targets/common.mk:295: recipe for target 'debian/stamp/build/kernel' failed
make: *** [debian/stamp/build/kernel] Error 2
```

How do I compile the.deb package and if I cant is there anything to do with the vmlinux and vmlinux.o files?

Comment: Why have you used the "elementary" tag?

Comment: The error message quite clearly says that you are missing the `lz4c` utility.

Answer (score 5):

The change to using LZ4 compression by default in Ubuntu kernel configurations is relatively recent. Not only do some older Ubuntu versions not have LZ4 related tools installed by default, but they are actually unavailable.

Change the compression method back to gzip: Method 1:

```
scripts/config --disable KERNEL_LZ4
scripts/config --enable KERNEL_GZIP
```

Method 2: Manually make these changes to your kernel config:

Change this:

```
#
# General setup
#
CONFIG_INIT_ENV_ARG_LIMIT=32
# CONFIG_COMPILE_TEST is not set
# CONFIG_HEADER_TEST is not set
CONFIG_LOCALVERSION=""
# CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO is not set
CONFIG_BUILD_SALT=""
CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_GZIP=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_BZIP2=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_LZMA=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_XZ=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_LZO=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_LZ4=y
# CONFIG_KERNEL_GZIP is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_BZIP2 is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_LZMA is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_XZ is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_LZO is not set
CONFIG_KERNEL_LZ4=y
```

To This:

```
#
# General setup
#
CONFIG_INIT_ENV_ARG_LIMIT=32
# CONFIG_COMPILE_TEST is not set
# CONFIG_HEADER_TEST is not set
CONFIG_LOCALVERSION=""
# CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO is not set
CONFIG_BUILD_SALT=""
CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_GZIP=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_BZIP2=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_LZMA=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_XZ=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_LZO=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_LZ4=y
CONFIG_KERNEL_GZIP=y
# CONFIG_KERNEL_BZIP2 is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_LZMA is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_XZ is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_LZO is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_LZ4 is not set
```

Note: It takes about double the compile time to include the debug information as per the default Ubuntu kernel settings. Suggest to disable:

```
scripts/config --disable DEBUG_INFO
```

Which should do this:

```
doug@s15:~/temp-k-git/linux$ scripts/diffconfig .config-5.4.0-050400-lowlatency .config
 DEBUG_INFO y -> n
doug@s15:~/temp-k-git/linux$ diff .config-5.4.0-050400-lowlatency .config
10144c10144
< CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
---
> # CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO is not set
```

Install only the resulting headers (~12 megabytes) and image (~60 megabytes) files.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. No I got 4 files the namely, linux-headers-5.3.10_5.3.10-1_amd64.deb(11MB), linux-libc-dev_5.3.10-1_amd64.deb(1.1MB), linux-image-5.3.10_5.3.10-1_amd64.deb(59.6MB) and linux-image-5.3.10-dbg_5.3.10-1_amd64.deb(841.6MB). I installed the 841.6MB kernel and headers using dpkg -i. Ran update-grub but the kernel is not installed. Its not there in /boot

Comment: Opps, if you are using the Ubuntu kernel configuration, you also need to disable debug stuff. I'll edit my answer. Install the 59.6 MB linux-image.

Answer (score 1):

```
/bin/sh: 1: lz4c: not found
kernel/4.14/arch/x86/boot/compressed/Makefile:141: recipe for target 'arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux.bin.lz4' failed 4:14
```

**Solution**: [all i had to do is install the missing library]
sudo apt-get install liblz4-tool